# How to fix "Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed" in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler

I'm trying to deploy a very basic Rails app to a brand new Heroku app. I connected the Heroku app to the GitHub repo and triggered the first deploy. Heroku can't build the app because "Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed".

This is the build log with the error highlighted with `!` and some parts hidden for brevity `[...]`:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.3
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       [...]
       Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 59 gems now installed.
       [...]
       Bundle completed (47.25s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
-----> Installing yarn-v1.16.0
-----> Detecting rake tasks
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
 !     Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_19c87a31c0181b0ad80a21cb76d32d96/Gemfile.lock.
 !     To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
 !     To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
 !     Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/tmp/build_19c87a31c0181b0ad80a21cb76d32d96/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
 !     
 !     To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.1'`
 !
       [...]
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

I followed the instructions in the error message, but it didn't solve the problem:

```
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.

$ bundle exec rake -P
[...] # long output, but yes, I can run it.

$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake -P
[...] # long output, but again I can run it.

 !     Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
 !     Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_19c87a31c0181b0ad80a21cb76d32d96/Gemfile.lock.
 !     To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
 !     To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`

# I'm already using bundler 2.0.1:
$ bundler --version
Bundler version 2.0.1
```

[Heroku says it supports bundler 2.X](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1563):

> The Ruby buildpack will now inspect the contents of the Gemfile.lock and use a version of bundler based on the BUNDLED WITH declaration.

My Gemfile.lock specifies BUNDLED WITH 2.0.1:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs: [...]

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  [...]

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.3p62

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.1
```

What should I fix?

Comment: Probably the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56793964/3784008). And if you're going to say "I did what the logs say to do and it still happens" then you should say in your post **exactly** what things you did to fix it and where you did those steps and **exactly** what the output of those things was especially when we're talking about a 242 line log. And keep your example code minimal; at least half your Gemfile is comments, whitespace, and environments not used by bundler.

Comment: @anothermh Thank you for the suggestions. I updated the question accordingly. Unfortunately the thread you pointed isn't the solution, since BUNDLED_WITH is [important information](https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html) and [editing Gemfile.lock is a known bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134802/what-happens-when-modifying-gemfile-lock-directly).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by trial-and-error. I considered these lines from the build log:

```
 -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
 [...]
 !     Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
 !     Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_19c87a31c0181b0ad80a21cb76d32d96/Gemfile.lock.
```

Heroku uses bundler 2.0.2 and I initially thought it would be able to install a 2.0.1 Gemfile.lock. Turns out it wasn't. I deleted the Gemfile.lock, installed bundler 2.0.2 and used it to bundle again:

```sh
rm Gemfile.lock
gem install bundler
bundle --version # Make sure the output is 2.0.2
bundle install
```

This regenerated Gemfile.lock now `BUNDLED WITH 2.0.2`, then I was able to deploy to Heroku successfully.

Comment: This can have negative impact on application as it will install those gems which are there without versions with latest versions.

best way is to just change bundler version in Gemile.lock in the end.